# CSSLint : How to config tasks just print error not warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, gruntjs, csslint

I'm new with Grunt - csslint plugin, after I run and cssLint task complete, there are many and many errors and warnings that I can't follow. So how to config task just print out the errors, not warning??

Comment: Maybe try the command line: https://github.com/stubbornella/csslint/wiki/Command-line-interface

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use [grunt-contrib-csslint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-csslint) you can specify the options in a `.csslintrc` file.

From the grunt-contrib-csslint Readme:

> **Options**
>
> Any specified option will be passed through directly to csslint, thus
>   you can specify any option that csslint supports. The csslint API is a
>   bit awkward: For each rule, a value of false ignores the rule, a value
>   of 2 will set it to become an error. Otherwise all rules are
>   considered warnings.

Assuming you have a structure like this:

```
├── .csslintrc
├── Gruntfile.js
├── css
│   └── foo.css
├── node_modules
└── package.json
```

**.csslintrc**

`{
    "ignore": [
        "adjoining-classes",
        "box-model",
        "box-sizing",
        "bulletproof-font-face",
        "compatible-vendor-prefixes",
        "display-property-grouping",
        "duplicate-background-images",
        "duplicate-properties",
        "empty-rules",
        "fallback-colors",
        "floats",
        "font-faces",
        "font-sizes",
        "gradients",
        "ids",
        "import",
        "import-ie-limit",
        "important",
        "known-properties",
        "non-link-hover",
        "order-alphabetical",
        "outline-none",
        "overqualified-elements",
        "qualified-headings",
        "regex-selectors",
        "rules-count",
        "selector-max",
        "selector-max-approaching",
        "selector-newline",
        "shorthand",
        "star-property-hack",
        "text-indent",
        "underscore-property-hack",
        "unique-headings",
        "universal-selector",
        "unqualified-attributes",
        "vendor-prefix",
        "zero-units"
    ]
}`

reference: https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Command-line-interface

**Gruntfile**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    csslint: {
      strict: {
        src: ['css/*.css']
      },
      lax: {
        options: {
          csslintrc: '.csslintrc'
        },
        src: ['css/*.css']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-csslint');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['csslint:lax']);
};
```

Then `grunt` will report only errors and `grunt csslint:strict` will report warnings and errors.